# Multiple column search in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this data set.

[image]

At A9 and B9, I have used the "List" option under the "Data validation" tab to get the dropdown option. The result at C9 should be populated from the above matrix.

[image]

In this example, C9 should have "NA"

Regards - Anil

Comment: What formula are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to build a formula

`=OFFSET($A$1;MATCH(A9;$A$2:$A$5;0);MATCH(B9;$B$1:$E$1;0))`

In general terms, this is [**written as**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-value-from-a-rectangular-table/1029)

`=OFFSET(<start_of_table>;N(MATCH(<row_header>;<first_column_of_table>;0));N(MATCH(<column_header>;<first_row_of_table>;0)))`

Comment: I think he wants the look up value from ABC and Europe (which have dropdowns)

Comment: @Prema Yes, that's right, exactly as described in the question. Are you confused by using OFFSET() instead of INDEX()? Don't worry, both formulas, both yours and mine, give the same result.

Comment: you are right! Different, but interesting approach!

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX(A1:E5;MATCH(A9;A1:A5;0);MATCH(B9;A1:E1;0))
```